# What is this error? - FAILED DURING THE BUILDING PHASE

Tags: regex, haskell, scope, ghc

I got this error while building:

```
dist/package.conf.inplace:
inappropriate type

FAILED DURING THE BUILDING PHASE. The **exception** was: ExitFailure 1
```

How do I use `subRegex` **in package** Text.Regex?

I have written:

```
import Text.Regex.Posix
```

But I got this error:

```
_.hs:13:5: Not in scope: ‘subRegex’

_.hs:13:15:
    Not in scope: ‘mkRegex’
    Perhaps you meant ‘makeRegex’ (imported from Text.Regex.Posix)
```

So, I went to `Text.Regex`'s [page][1], and there it said:

> Uses the POSIX regular expression interface in `Text.Regex.Posix`.

*So why not aren't these functions in-scope?*

Comment: Notice `Text.Regex` is not a package.  It is a module in the regex-compat package.

Answer (score 9):

Here are some steps you can perform to make it working.

1. Download from http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-compat-0.92, unzip to **<Haskell Platform INSTALL FOLDER>**\2014.2.0.0\lib\
2. Run Haskell.
3. Type `:mod +Text.Regex` to load the package.
4. Type, e.g. `subRegex (mkRegex "[0-9]+") "foobar567" "123"`
5. Result is `"foobar123"` (after all packages are loaded).

Here is the [**subRegex** description](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-compat-0.92/docs/Text-Regex.html):

> `:: Regex     Search pattern`
>   
> `-> String    Input string`
>   
> `-> String    Replacement text`
>   
> `-> String    Output string`
>
> Replaces every occurance of the given regexp with the replacement
>   string.
>
> In the replacement string, "\1" refers to the first substring; "\2" to
>   the second, etc; and "\0" to the entire match. "\\" will insert a
>   literal backslash.
>
> This does not advance if the regex matches an empty string. This
>   misfeature is here to match the behavior of the the original
>   Text.Regex API.

Some cool links that can help you delve deeper:
http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2007/02/27/a-haskell-regular-expression-tutorial/, and 
https://wiki.haskell.org/Cookbook/Pattern_matching.

I am using it in Windows, here is my screen:

[image]

Comment: i got this error while building: failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1

Comment: in my log it says: dist/package.conf.inplace:
inappropriate type

Comment: Let me first mention that by logging another ticket (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837198/macosx-cabal-install-built-failed-during-the-building-phase-the-exception-wa) you admit it is already a separate question. Now, there is http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/ with nice cabal installation info. Then, at http://ircbrowse.net/browse/haskell?events_page=4&q=Dist, you can check for several possible solutions: 1) remove /dist folder using  `rm -rf dist` and then `cabal install`, 2) get the latest build from https://www.haskell.org/ghc/ (GHC 7.10.1 works with cabal-install version 1.22+).

Comment: I see you included the code that worked for you in the question. Basically, it is the same code as mine, as you are using `subRegex` from `Text.Regex` module.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't import `Text.Regex.Posix`, but rather **just `Text.Regex`**, because the two functions you want are there.

Have a look at [the Hackage page](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-compat-0.92/docs/Text-Regex.html) - you were almost there, but the functions where actually in that file.

Comment: I'm using ghci but I still run into erro. help! I tried doing that & compile it also run into errorrrr

Comment: @Help-Ineedsomebody'shelp We cannot help you if you don't tell us the errror.

Comment: @Eric GOT THIS EROORORORO: failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1

Comment: in my log it says dist/package.conf.inplace:
inappropriate type