# MacOSX - cabal install: built failed during the building phase. The exception was: ExitFailure 1 - dist/package.conf.inplace: inappropriate type

Tags: haskell, cabal

using cabal; came accross this error.

did `cabal install` and this **happened**.

> failed during the building phase. The exception was:
>   ExitFailure 1

checked my log; it **said**:

> dist/package.conf.inplace:
>   inappropriate type

I have **0 ideas** what's going on. **`cabal build` works though**. #STRANGE

### CURRENTLY:

### CABAL version: 1.22.0.0. Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation version: 7.8.4

Answer (score 3):

Possible explanation: you have upgraded GHC to 7.10, which does things a bit differently I gather, but not upgraded cabal-install. If this is the problem, running

```
cabal install cabal-install -w ghc-7.8.4 # or whatever other version of GHC you have
```

may fix the problem.

Comment: thank you; that makes sense; it should fix the problem I hope; can't recall when it did the install though

Comment: Is it normal that it takes a while for `cabal install cabal-install`?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error if you previously built your package with an older (or newer) version of Cabal and now are building with a newer (or older) version.

Not enough information to determine whether this is the problem in your case.

If it is, I think `cabal clean` should fix it (though I usually just `rm -rf dist`).